# Toll free bridging Monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I've got a problem with monotouch. Im not sure how to do toll free bridging.

My code is

```
    NSInputStream iStream;
    NSOutputStream oStream;

    CFWriteStream cfWrite;
    CFReadStream cfRead;
    CFStream.CreatePairWithSocketToHost(server, port, out cfRead, out cfWrite);
    iStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream)cfRead;
```

Ok so (__bridge) etc. doesn't exist, but simple casting like

```
    iStream = (NSInputStream)cfRead;
```

also won't work.

Which is the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

NSInputStream constructor is not directly accessible anymore. Use this instead:

```
using ObjCRuntime;
...
iStream = Runtime.GetNSObject<NSInputStream>(cfRead.Handle);
```

See here: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/corefoundation.cfstream?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)